# Django : How to check if element in the queryset?

Tags: django

I'd liket to make is current_user exist in queryset, so i try:

```
{% if obj.payer.name == current_user.username %}
    {{ obj.price|intcomma }} / {{obj.dutch_payer.all.count}}</p>
    <p>={{ obj.price|div_payer_me:obj.dutch_payer.all.count|intcomma }}</p>
{% else %}
    {% if current_user.username in obj.dutch_payer.filter(name=current_user.username) %}
        {{ obj.price|intcomma }} / {{obj.dutch_payer.all.count|add1}}</p>
        <p>={{ obj.price|div_payer_notme:obj.dutch_payer.all.count|intcomma }}</p>
    {% else %}
        0
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

but error occur :

> Could not parse the remainder: '(name=current_user.username)' from 'obj.dutch_payer.filter(name=current_user.username)'

**Tempfriend model:**

```
class Tempfriend(core_models.TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    belongs_to = models.ForeignKey(
        user_models.User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="belongs_to")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**moneylog model:**

```
class Moneylog(core_models.TimeStampedModel):

    moneybook = models.ForeignKey(
        moneybook_models.Moneybook, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pay_day = models.DateTimeField(default=NOW)
    payer = models.ForeignKey(
        tempfriend_models.Tempfriend, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="payer")
    dutch_payer = models.ManyToManyField(
        tempfriend_models.Tempfriend, related_name="dutch_payer", blank=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    memo = models.TextField()

    objects = models.Manager()
```

as you see, dutch_payer and current_user is different model.

How can I check the is there current_user in dutch_payer?

**Tried:**

```
@register.filter
def user_in_dutch_payers(current_user, obj):
    return obj.dutch_payer.filter(name=current_user.username).exists()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use queries directly in template (templates are writen in [Django template language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/language/#the-django-template-language)). Instead you can use [simple tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags):

Add your custom tag(s) in `settings.py`:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'OPTIONS': {
        'builtins': [
            'myprojectname.templatetags.custom_tags',
```

Next, put this file inside your app `templatetags/custom_tags.py`

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def user_in_dutch_payers(current_user, obj):
    return obj.dutch_payer.filter(name=current_user.username).exists()
```

And finally use tag in **template**:

```
{% user_in_dutch_payers current_user obj as check_user_in_dutch_payers %}
{% if check_user_in_dutch_payers %} 
    {{ obj.price|intcomma }} / {{obj.dutch_payer.all.count|add1}}</p>
    <p>={{ obj.price|div_payer_notme:obj.dutch_payer.all.count|intcomma }}</p>
{% else %}
    0
{% endif %}
```

Comment: instead of using tags, I build a filter(.simple_tag than .filter) but 
>valid block tag on line 57: 'user_in_dutch_payers', expected 'endif'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
error occur. I load the tag in template and I guess everything is find. do you know the solution?

Comment: You need to post the code and full exception message. As for now it's not obvious about what filter your are talking and what you actually did.

Comment: I updated my custom what I tried in templatetags>custom.py. when I tried that, it doens't work with the error what I wrote above comment. but after I edit it like yours(ex:@register.simple_tag) It works. What is the difference??

Comment: @dhooonk because of the template language specifics you need to use [with](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#with) in order to combine `if` statement and your filter.

Comment: You mean 'check_user_in_dutch_payers' is populated variable so, I need to write {% with check_user_in_dutch_payers = user_in_dutch_payers(current_user, obj) %} ?

Comment: No, it'll be something like this: `{% with result=check_user_in_dutch_payers|current_user: obs %}  {% if result %} ... `

Comment: I totally understand and really Thanks for your kindess help. Hope you to be a good day. Thanks.